# Dynamically query or filter a table in Google Sheets using checkboxes and searchbox

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a database of songs and want to use filter or query to return results based on a dashboard with search-boxes and check-boxes. This seems rudimentary, but I can't find what I'm looking for after a few days. Query seems super powerful, but largely when hard coding. I need a user-friendly interface! I've seen some tutorials on incorporating drop-down boxes, but I don't necessarily want to use those.

I couldn't figure out how to add IF() statements to the WHERE clause in query.

```
=QUERY(A4:G9, "WHERE IF '"(C2=TRUE, "' '"C CONTAINS TRUE"'",1))
```

This is what I'm starting with, and I know its all kinds of wrong.

GOAL: When the checkbox for MP3 is ticked, all songs with MP3s are listed. But when I also tick the WAV box, only songs with MP3s and WAVs remain, etc.

[image]

I will keep the source data and the search key on different tabs. Eventually like to add ranges to the length and bpm boxes too.

Any suggestions on the methods or formulas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please read: [Query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

```
=query(A4:G9,"select A,B,C where 0=0"&IF($B$2," and B=TRUE","")&IF($C$2," and C=TRUE",""),1)
```

Comment: I read that document, thanks for sharing. I am new to query, so what I still didn't get from reading that was some of the finer points of syntax. I'm a little confused still on how to integrate regular Google Sheets formulas with query language. Clearly the use of the ampersand `&` is key.  Your code worked great, but how do I integrate a search box to that string of parameters?

`WHERE D CONTAINS '" & C2 &"'`

Comment: your code looks fine just build more if statements.

Comment: OK I got this code to work: `=QUERY(A4:G9,"SELECT * WHERE 0=0"&IF($B$2," AND B=TRUE","")&IF($C$2," AND C=TRUE","")&IF($D$2<>"", " AND D CONTAINS '"&$D$2&"'",""),1)` This works and will return all the parameters that meet this criteria AND that. However, how do I code it if I want to return all the songs that meet this criteria OR that criteria? I tried replacing some of the `AND`'s to `OR`'s, but then the results just ignore my input in those boxes. `=QUERY(A4:G9,"SELECT * WHERE 0=0"&IF($B$2," OR B=TRUE","")&IF($C$2," OR C=TRUE","")&IF($D$2<>"", " OR D CONTAINS '"&$D$2&"'",""),1)`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G, "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, 
 IF(B2=TRUE, "B=TRUE", ), 
 IF(C2=TRUE, "C=TRUE", )), 1), QUERY(A4:G))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G, "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, 
 IF(B2=TRUE, "B=TRUE", ), 
 IF(C2=TRUE, "C=TRUE", ), 
 IF(F1<>"", "lower(D) contains '"&F1&"'", )), 1), QUERY(A4:G))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Instead of an iferror I prefer putting 0=0 after WHERE to fulfill the requirement

Comment: This is great!!